# Using a shared service within a class

Tags: java, class, oop, static, shared-memory

I have a class ServerFactory like the following:

```
public class ServerFactory{
private static Server sharedServer=null;

public static getSharedServer(){...}
}
```

I have a utility class like:

```
public class AUtils{
private Server server;
public AUtils(){
this.server = ServerFactory.getSharedServer();
}}
```

Question: What happens every time I create an instance of AUtils? Will I use the only static instance from the server factory or each AUtils object will have a separate server instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll use the static instance each time. In `AUtils` class, you just refer to the actual [singleton](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073352/core-java/simply-singleton.html) instance which was created only once.

By the way, I assume that the code is as follows:

```
public static getSharedServer(){
    if(sharedServer == null) {
         sharedServer = ... //create server instance
    }
    return sharedServer;
}
```

Comment: I would also add to be careful with this implementation since it generates a memory leak.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza What exactly would create a memory leak in such a case? Having the `server` variable?

Comment: When you store a singleton reference in a field of your object reference, then you will always have a reference to an object that won't be GCed until the class is unloaded. Since the class won't be unloaded (typical configuration for JVM) then the singleton reference won't be GCed and will always be live, so your object reference that has a reference to this singleton reference won't be GCed as well. And if you create lot of instances of your class that contains a reference to this singleton reference, you will encounter OOM.

Comment: Hmm, I have never tested such a case; but why wouldn't the referring object GCed e.g. an `AUtils` instance? Even if it uses a living resource, it should be GCed if there are no other resources using it.. It seems as the reasonable way to me..